# How to get number of entities returned in a Azure Tables query?

Tags: python, azure-table-storage

I am using python to make a query to Azure tables.

```
    query = table_service.query_entities(table_name, filter=filter_string)
```

How can I see the amount of entities returned by this query? I have tried using

```
query.count
query.count()
```

but have had no luck. I get the following error.

> 'ListGenerator' object has no attribute 'count

Searching online keeps bring back results about getting the count of the entire rows in the table which is not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `len(query.items)` to get the number of returned entities.

The code like below:

```
query = table_service.query_entities(table_name, filter=filter_string)

print(len(query.items))
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a new SDK for the Azure tables service, you can install it from pip with the command `pip install azure-data-tables`. The new SDK can target either a storage account or a cosmos account. Here is a sample of how you can find the total number of entities in a table. You will have to iterate through each entity because the new Tables SDK uses paging on calls for `query_entities` and `list_entities`. Entities are turned in an `ItemPaged` which only returns a subset of the entities at a time.

```py
from azure.data.tables import TableClient, TableServiceClient

connection_string = "<your_conn_str>"
table_name = "<your_table_name>"

with TableClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, table_name) as table_client:

    f = "value gt 25"

    query = table_client.query_entities(filter=f)

    count = 0
    for entity in query:
        count += 1

    print(count)
```

If you can clarify why you need the number of entities in a query I might be able to give better advice.

(Disclaimer, I work on the Azure SDK for Python team)